# ViewBag.Title from Vue router

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, vuejs2

How can I change this title with `meta.title` from Vue router?

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
```

Comment: Is this for server-side rendering, or are you asking about this in general? Your code executes on the server as part of ASP.NET Core. At that time, no JavaScript has been executed, so Vue didn’t run and as such cannot affect the title yet. So you will have to follow a client-side solution to set the title dynamically. See for example [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/914) for some solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added this in main.js:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    document.title = to.meta.title + ' - WebSite'
    next()
});
```

And this in all routes:

```
meta: { 
    title: 'Page Title',
}
```

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define title attribute under metaTags in where you define route please refer an example for more details.
https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-router-modify-head/